# Sessions cannot be booked after someone cancels

Tags: wordpress, plugins

we seem to be getting a bug where if someone cancels a reservation and that slot then becomes available again, that particular time slot cannot be booked. See screenshot attached.

After receiving complaints from people trying to book, I tried booking a slot, cancelling it and booking again and this replicated the issue they were having.

Comment: there's no screenshot attached and it doesn't seem to be related to programming either